# How Can I Cause Back Button to Return Directly from Google Play to my App that Launched it if Play app has Non-Empty Stack?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, back

I am launching Google Play from my App's HelpActivity as follows:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:\"Some Developer\"");
Intent playIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
playIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY 
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);              
startActivity(playIntent);
```

Just prior to executing this code, I manually enter Google Play, select Apps from the first page, and then select the currently-featured app (in this case, Pandora).  This establishes a stack internal to Google Play, through which the Back button will return if pressed while inside Google Play.

When the above code is run, Google Play appears and navigates to the list of Some Developer's applications, as expected.

The problem is that when I then press the Back button, I go back through the Google Play stack, visiting Pandora, and then the main Apps page, and then the main page of Google Play, before finally returning to my own app (on the fourth press of the Back button).

What I would like to occur is to have the Back button take me directly back to my own app, leaving the previously-established stack of the Google Play app as my app originally found it.

I've tried various combinations of the Intent flags, but to no avail.

I should add that my app is targeting API 8.

The HelpActivity is itself launched from my main activity when the user presses Help on the main activity's options menu.  Here is the code that performs that launch:

```
.
.
.
else if(itemID == R.id.menu_help) {
  Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
  helpIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  helpIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  startActivity(helpIntent);
}
```

Also, the HelpActivity is declared in an unusual manner within the manifest for my app:

```
   <activity android:name="com.mycompany.HelpActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_help"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|locale|mcc|mnc|touchscreen|screenLayout|fontScale"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"
              android:taskAffinity="com.mycompany.helpactivity"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
              android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
              android:process=":fbhelp"
              android:stateNotNeeded="true"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              >
```

A few of these attributes seem as though they might relate to this issue, which is why I'm including this part of my manifest.  This activity runs in its own process to avoid consuming heap within my main app.  It is excluded from recents because I don't want the user to see it as separate from my app.  It is singleInstance to prevent a buildup of invisible instances in case the user launches it more than one time.

I've tried various Intent flags, but nothing seems to attain the result that I'm seeking.

I've found that this anomalous behavior is reliably reproducible on my Nexus One phone running Android 2.3.3.

I've also reproduced it on my Moto Droid running Android 2.2.1, CyanogenMod-6.1.0-Droid, and the anomalous behavior is also present there.  It's running the Android Market app, not Google Play; I have no plans to update, since this is a test device, and most users will not go through the process of manually updating.

I've also reproduced it on my G1 running Android 2.2.1, CyanogenMod-6.1.0-DS, which is also running the old Android Market app.

However, it is completely absent on my GTablet running 2.3.3.  So, it may be somewhat OS (flavor of CM7), or GP app, specific and therefore of less general interest, although as you can see there are a number of platforms and devices that exhibit it.  It also may be difficult for others to reproduce unless you happen to have a device that exhibits the anomaly.

Please see comments below for further discussion.

Comment: Did you try adding the "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" flag for the intent?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Yes, I tried that flag, but the result was the same as I have described above.  In response to your question, I have just tried it again to be sure I was not mistaken, and, unfortunately, it indeed does not have the desired effect.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html from the documentation given regarding navigation, the scenario you describe should not arise.

Comment: I tried to simulate the bihaviour you described, but I was unable to reproduce it. I did these steps: 1. Opened GP. 2. Selected one featured app to view its details. 3. Run your code from Eclipse. 4. Pressed BACK. Pressing BACK I was taken to my main activity, instead of featured app details page. (Samsung Galaxy Ace)

Comment: @Andy Res: Thanks for trying this.  I should have been clearer: my helpactivity is not my main activity.  helpactivity is itself being launched from my main activity in response to the user pressing Help option on my main app's options menu.  The android:process attribute causes help to be launched in its own process, which may have something to do with my issue; I'm not certain.  I will edit my question now to show how this occurs.

Comment: @Gogu:  Thanks for that document link.  Yes, in that document it states that:

"The system Back button is used to navigate, in reverse chronological order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between screens, rather than the app's hierarchy."

You're correct that what I'm experiencing is not consistent with that desired behavior.  In fact, it seems as though the Back button is behaving in the manner that the Up button should behave; but I'm running in Android 2.2.1, which has no Up button.  Thus my dilemma.

Comment: @Gogu: The word "generally" in the above may be operative here :-).  Note this later section of the same document:  "However, a notable exception to this occurs when browsing between related detail views not tied together by the referring list—for example, when browsing in the Play Store between apps from the same developer..."  My request brings up exactly such a list of "apps by the same developer."  "In these cases, following each link does create history, causing the Back button to step through each previously viewed screen."  That's intriguing, but I don't actually follow the links...

Comment: @Gogu:  This part still later in the document seems analogous to my own situation, and the results are indeed different: 

"When the user elects to share via Gmail, Gmail's compose activity is added as a continuation of Task A—no new task is created. If Gmail had its own task running in the background, it would be unaffected.  From the compose activity, sending the message or touching the Back button returns the user to the book details activity..."

So the user specifically does *not* get stuck in any pre-existing (Gmail) activity stack that might exist.  But that is what is happening to me.

Comment: Correction to the above:  My Nexus One phone, which exhibits the problem, is running Gingerbread (specifically, Android 2.3.3, CyanogenMod-7.0.0-N1), not 2.2.1, as stated above.

Also, I've noticed that the anomalous behavior does NOT occur on my GTablet, which is running 2.3.3 as well (CyanogenMod-7.0.3-Harmony).

Also, the correct behavior is consistent on the GTab no matter what apps I select in Google Play, and the incorrect behavior is consistent, regardless of app, on the N1.